# Summing Row values together based on index value and conditional statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I am trying to automate a process where multiple items have similar indexes.

For example, the index may be:

```
12345 - Banana - Green 
12346 - Banana - Yellow
12347 - Banana - Brown
12348 - Orange - Orange
```

I need to be able to sum the rows of "banana" into 1 singular row that is the total of all the individual "banana" rows.

Would there be a way to be able to sum the values in the banana rows automatically?  I don't want to use a matching conditional for only "banana" due to trying to automate this process for almost any keyword.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method is for you. See this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon',
...                               'Parrot', 'Parrot'],
...                    'Max Speed': [380., 370., 24., 26.]})
>>> df
   Animal  Max Speed
0  Falcon      380.0
1  Falcon      370.0
2  Parrot       24.0
3  Parrot       26.0

grouped_df = df.groupby(['Animal']).sum()
>>> grouped_dp
        Max Speed
Animal
Falcon      750.0
Parrot       50.0
```

You can query the dataframe like this:

```
>>> grouped_df[(grouped_df.index == 'Parrot') & (grouped_df['Max Speed']>10)]
        Max Speed
Animal           
Parrot       50.0
```

Comment: I'm trying not to use a static keyword if possible.  My keywords are fluid, so each time i run my data i would have to reenter "falcon" or "parrot" with the new keyword.  Is there a way I could search character by character or something?